# Java Stream forEach Loop with Multiple Conditions

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, java-stream

I have a forEach loop and for performance issues I'm told to use Java stream instead of this. I have multiple cases and my code is like below. I couldn't found any stream example with multiple cases. Could anyone help me to convert this? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
name = "Serena";
for(Integer age : ages){
   if(age>10 && age<20)
        methodA(name);
   else if(age>20 && age<30)
        methodB(name);
   else
        methodC(name);
```

Answer (score 4):

For the updated question, Stream API may be used to map the age into `Consumer<String>` using references to methods `methodA, methodB, methodC` and then invoke `Consumer::accept` but this does not seem to be very useful and can be considered just as an exercise:

```java
public static void main(String .... args) {
    List<Integer> ages = Arrays.asList(1, 10, 15, 20, 22, 30, 33);

    ages.stream()
        .map(MyClass::byAge)
        .forEach(action -> action.accept("Serena"));
}

// mapper to specific method
static Consumer<String> byAge(int age) {
    return 10 < age && age < 20
            ? MyClass::methodA
            : 20 < age && age < 30
            ? MyClass::methodB
            : MyClass::methodC;
}

// consumer methods
public static void methodA(String name) {
    System.out.println("A: " + name);
}

public static void methodB(String name) {
    System.out.println("B: " + name);
}

public static void methodC(String name) {
    System.out.println("C: " + name);
}
```

Comment: could we use "switch" as express in the `byAge` method?  (not quite up to speed with the latest and greatest in Java :))

Comment: @Gavin, does `switch` statement support ranges in some newer version of Java?  Afaik, only constant values are allowed for `case`.  The ranges in this example could be replaced with something like `return switch (age) { case 11, 12, 13,...19 -> MyClass:methodA; case 21, 22, 23,... 29 -> MyClass:methodB; default -> MyClass:methodC;}`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I guess I got mixed up with all the preview features and proposals :)

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(11, 22, 30, 40);

ints.forEach(i -> {
        if (i> 10 && i < 20) {
            System.out.println("Value between 10 & 20");
        } else if(i >= 20 && i < 30) {
            System.out.println("Value between 20 & 30");
        } else if(i>=30 && i <40) {
            System.out.println("Value between 30 & 40");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I applied this to my code but I updated the question because I'm having trouble with passing a parameter to the methods. Could you please help me about this, too? Thanks.

Comment: Make `name` final.  For a lambda to use a captured variable it most be _effectively_ final.

Comment: Thank you. Should I check the list to see if it is null or stream checks it automatically?

Comment: @Serena your methods mark methodA, methodB , methodC as Static if ur invoking the code into ur main method , see if that works.

Comment: No need of `stream()`  when you use `forEach`

Comment: @Serena if the list is null then attempting to `stream` will cause a `NullPointerException` if the list is empty the stream will complete without executing any of it operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use forEach with your code. Not sure if this is what you want or why.

```
ages.forEach(age -> {
    if(age > 10 && age < 20) {
        methodA(age);
    }
    else if(age > 20 && age < 30) {
        methodB(age);
    }
    else {
        methodC(age);
    }
});
```

Comment: No need of `stream()`  when you use `forEach`

Comment: True but the question was how to use a stream :-)

Comment: Also if ages is an array you would have to use IntStream.of(ages)

Comment: I always considered `List.forEach` a stream, as I assumed it was just a shortcut for `List.stream.forEach`

Comment: You're probably right. Doesn't really matter though. I'd go for the shorter version so I updated my answer. Although I generally prefer using stream().map() to differentiate between methodA, B and C, make them return something and then process that result. But that wasn't really the question.